# How to split string using one pattern?

Tags: php, regex, split

I have a string such as:

```
84 - Pampers mid (4-9кг) №180  [Procter&Gamble] - 1978.00
```

And i need to divide it to array (php), something like:

```
[0] 84
[1] Pampers mid (4-9кг) №180
[2] Procter&Gamble
[3] 1978.00
```

At that moment i am doing it step-by-step:

```
$pattern = '/\[(.*)\]/';//producer
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches_producer);
$provider=$matches_producer[1];
...
```

and so on for each element.

But this is ugly method, isn't it? How i can make it with one pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine all regex's into one to extract all values into `$match` at once:

```
$string = "84 - Pampers mid (4-9кг) №180  [Procter&Gamble] - 1978.00";
preg_match('/(\d+) - (.*) \[(.*)\] - (\d+.\d+)/', $string, $match);
```

After running this code `$match` contains:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 84 - Pampers mid (4-9кг) №180  [Procter&Gamble] - 1978.00
    [1] => 84
    [2] => Pampers mid (4-9кг) №180 
    [3] => Procter&Gamble
    [4] => 1978.00
)
```

If you have a lot of these strings in an array you might consider using [preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thank you, I didn't knew that. I changed it in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

something like

```
$x = '84 - Pampers mid (4-9кг) №180  [Procter&Gamble] - 1978.00';
preg_match_all('/(\d*)\ \-\ (.*)\ \[(.*)\]\ \-\ (.*)/', $x, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```